# mass rename brings errors

Tags: bash, loops, rename

I have got the following files in current dir:

```
file_73tyd7d.jpg
file_e8djuh.jpeg
file_eidie8d.jpg
file_iadiijj.jpg
```

I want:

```
0.jpg
1.jpeg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

I first do:

```
NB=0;for FILE in `ls`;do echo mv "${FILE}" "${NB}.${FILE#*.*}";((NB=NB+1));done
```

or

```
NB=0;for FILE in `ls`;do echo mv "${FILE}" "${NB}"."${FILE#*.*}";((NB=NB+1));done
```

output:

```
file_73tyd7d.jpg 0.jpg  -> why is that? 
mv file_e8djuh.jpeg 1.jpeg
mv file_eidie8d.jpg 2.jpg
mv file_iadiijj.jpg 3.jpg
```

apart from the first file, it looks good. now I do:

```
NB=0;for FILE in `ls`;do mv "${FILE}" "${NB}.${FILE#*.*}";((NB=NB+1));done
```

and I have got the following error:

```
mv: cannot stat ''$'\033''[H'$'\033''[2J'$'\033''[3J'$'\033''[0m'$'\033''[01;35mfile_73tyd7d.jpg'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory

mv: cannot stat ''$'\033''[01;35mfile_e8djuh.jpeg'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory

mv: cannot stat ''$'\033''[01;35mfile_eidie8d.jpg'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory

mv: cannot stat ''$'\033''[01;35mfile_iadiijj.jpg'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is `ls` an alias to `ls --color=always`? Run `unalias ls` and try again

Comment: Use: `$(/usr/bin/ls)` (or `$(/bin/ls)`).  The `$(…)` notation is generally a better idea than backticks — if only because it is far easier to nest uses of `$(…)`.  And using `/usr/bin/ls` or `/bin/ls` avoids getting colours in the output; add `--color=never` if need be.  Another possibility is to use `command ls` instead of just `ls` — that avoids aliases and functions and so on.

Comment: @ismail: Nice! doing `\ls` instead of `ls` works! (the alias is effectively responsible for the trouble!)

Comment: Better yet, [don't parse `ls` at all](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), just use `for FILE in *;do`. `ls` is really intended to display lists of files to the users, not to get lists for processing in a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, do not use `ls` at all. `ls` is supposed to be used interactively (See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). Also, do not use all-caps names for your own variable names (See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)). Your script should have been written something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

nb=0
for file in *; do
    echo mv -i -- "$file" "$((nb++)).${file##*.}"
done
```